# Is there a way to unmask asteriks between words in jenkins console?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials, masking

I understood that reason for having asteriks in jenkins console output is because of using credentials method(Eg. for maven command). 
This credentials method will mask only credentials used with asteriks in jenkins console.
But in my case it is masking the space between two words also with 4 asteriks.

Expecting normal spaces between two words instead of having asteriks while using credentials method in jenkinsfile